# CouchDb views not updating

Tags: objective-c, couchdb

Okay I'm currently using CouchDb v 1.2.0 for a scheme application with objective-c. When i run my program I'm deleting the old version of the database and creating a new one like this:

```
CouchDb *couchDb = [[CouchDb alloc]init];
        //Deleting the old version of the db if it exists for xcode demo
        [couchDb deleteDb:@"timevault" onComplete:^(NSString *message) {
            NSLog(@"%@", message); 
        }];
        //Creating a new db
        [couchDb createDb:@"timevault" onComplete:^(NSString *message) {
            NSLog(@"%@", message);
        }];
        //Creating views to get students and courses
        NSString *viewCourses = @"function (doc) {      if (doc.type === \"Course\") {        emit(doc._id, doc);      }    }";
        NSString *viewStudents = @"function (doc) {      if (doc.type === \"Student\") {        emit(doc._id, doc);      }    }";
        NSDictionary *views = @{@"views": @{@"courses": @{@"map":viewCourses}, @"students": @{@"map":viewStudents}}};

        //Saving design document to db
        [couchDb createViewInDb:views onComplete:^(NSString *message) {
            NSLog(@"%@", message);
        }];
```

Class implementation:

```
    -(void)deleteDb:(NSString *)name onComplete:(message)message{
        NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost:5984/"];
        [url appendString:name];
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
        NSURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)responseCode;
            NSNumber *responseStatusCode = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:[httpResponse statusCode]];
            if ([responseStatusCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:200]]) {
                message([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Old db %@ deleted", name]);
            }
        }else {
            message([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
        }
    }
-(void)createDb:(NSString *)name onComplete:(message)message{
    NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost:5984/"];
    [url appendString:name];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    NSURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)responseCode;
        NSNumber *responseStatusCode = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:[httpResponse statusCode]];
        if ([responseStatusCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:412]]) {
          message(@"Db already exists, no new Db was created");
        }else if ([responseStatusCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:201]]){
            message([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Db %@ created", name]);
        }
    }else {
        message([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
    }

}
-(void)createViewInDb:(NSDictionary *)view onComplete:(message)message{
    NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:URL];
    [url appendString:@"/_design/app"];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    NSData *asJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:view options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [request setHTTPBody:asJson];
    NSURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
    if (!error){
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)responseCode;
        NSNumber *responseStatusCode = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:[httpResponse statusCode]];
        if ([responseStatusCode isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:201]]) {
            message(@"Views in Db created");
        }
    }else {
        message([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
    }
}
```

All of this is with synchronous requests. **For the couchdb pros out there that doesn't know obj-c, I'm basically saying this:**

```
 DELETE http://localhost:5984/database/
 PUT http://localhost:5984/database/
 PUT http://localhost:5984/database/_design/app, 
 content-type: application/json
```

with body:

```
{"views":
  {
    "courses": {
      "map": "function (doc) {      
        if (doc.type === \"Course\") {        
         emit(doc._id, doc);
        }}"
       },
      "students": {
        "map": "function (doc) {      
         if (doc.type === \"Student\") {        
          emit(doc._id, doc);      
       }}"
      }}
    }
```

**My problem here is that my view:** `http://localhost:5984/database/_design/app/_view/students` only works like half of the time, the other half it's not updating, I'm getting old id's, why is this? 
I'm not looking at the old version of the db because I'm creating new documents of students and courses and that's working. Am I missing something when I'm deleting the db that concerns the _design document? I googled around on this but can't find anything that solves my problem.

Comment: Have you tried the `stale` parameter when you query the view?

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it for me too. You should mark your question as resolved :)